# jquery function in wordpress not loading in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using this jquery script to filter content from a html table .
http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/
The search bar works great when I type on the keyboard on desktop and mobile using the touchscreen.

I tried to load the same script in a wordpress page but it was not working . so I tried to wrap the code in this function

`(function($) {
})(jQuery);`

I think this is a method used for compatibility with wordpress jquery library.
It works fine in desktop but now the keyup event does not work on mobile .

Comment: how are you adding this to your wp site?

Comment: I'm using the shortcoder plugin to embed javascript and html code in the elementor builder . But I also tried to add the code inserting directly on a php custom page .

Answer (score 1):

WordPress dont't understand $ as jQuery and you have to make some modifications to fix this error. You can try wrap:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // your code jquery here
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // your code jquery here
});
```